# Why doesn't this MySQL query work?

Tags: mysql

I got this query that is not working, and I don't know what it is. I'm writing a email active scripts. This the URL;

```
http://www.example.com/activate.php?id=1&h=secretkey1
```

This is what `activate.php` looks like;

```
<?php
require "inc/connect.php";

$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
$hash = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['h']);

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id, h, active FROM tablename WHERE id=$id AND key=$hash") or die(mysql_error());  
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

if ($row['active'] == "1") {
    echo "error!";
}
elseif ($row['active'] == "0") {
    mysql_query("UPDATE tablename SET active=1 WHERE id='$id' AND key='$hash'");
}
?>
```

This is the error that I get;

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'key=secretkey1' at line 1

In my database I have a test field in `tablename` with;

```
id /    key    / active
------------------
1 / secretkey1 / 0
```

Comment: Is the different use of quotation marks in the two queries intentional? WHERE id=$id AND key=$hash vs WHERE id='$id' AND key='$hash'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Two reasons:

1) Because you need to enclose `secretkey1` (inside `$hash`) in single quotes, since it is a string and strings must be single-quoted. `$id` doesn't need to be quoted since you have cast it to an integer.

2) `KEY` is a [MySQL reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), and must be enclosed in backquotes to be used as a table or column name:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id, h, active FROM tablename WHERE id=$id AND `key`='$hash'") or die(mysql_error());
```

I note also that you are selecting `id, h, active` in your query but your example table has a column named `key`, not `h` (unless we don't see that column).

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I did have single quotes before, but tried removing them to see if it helped. Also it should be `key` in the query but even when using `*` I still get an error. With both single quotes and `select *` I now get this: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key='secretkey1'' at line 1`

Comment: @Linkjuice57 See change above. KEY is a reserved keyword.

Comment: Aha! Never would have figured that about by myself :)

Answer (score 2):

You have this:

```
 key=$hash
```

That should be:

```
 key='$hash'
```

---

By the way, as much as possible, use parameterized query to **prevent** sql injection attack.

Use PDO:

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

[Are PDO prepared statements sufficient to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: I thought that `mysql_real_escape_string` was good enough, thanks for the suggestion I'll check it out!

Comment: there are times it isn't enough http://johnroach.info/2011/02/17/why-mysql_real_escape_string-isnt-enough-to-stop-sql-injection-attacks/